In the ComplexHeatmap, how to change the anno_barplot() title's angle?
I use the R package,complexheatmap to draw a heatmap.
This is my code:
aa <- rowAnnotation("log10(FDR)" = anno_barplot(fdr), 
                    "log2(Fold Change)" = anno_barplot(fc, gp = gpar(fill = fc_color(fc))),
                    width = unit(3, 'cm'),
                    gap = unit(10, "points"))
Heatmap(matrix = mtx, 
             border = T, 
             column_order = ordered_sample, 
             heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "", 
             legend_height = unit(4, "cm")), column_names_rot = -90, 
             row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8), 
             column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8), 
             clustering_method_rows = "ward.D2", 
             name = "Scale(exp)", 
             cluster_column_slices = T, row_split = rr_,
             cluster_rows = T, 
             cluster_columns = F, 
             clustering_method_columns = "ward.D2",
             col = htmp_color, right_annotation = aa
        )


my question is how to turn log10(FDR) 90 degrees?
This way the titles of the two Barplplots will not overlap

It's better if you can supply some sample data. Using an alternative example, annotation_name_rot = 90 seems to do the trick (rotating foo2 and bar2 bottom right):
library(ComplexHeatmap)

set.seed(123)
mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 10)
rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:10)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:10)
column_ha = HeatmapAnnotation(foo1 = runif(10), bar1 = anno_barplot(runif(10)))
row_ha = rowAnnotation(foo2 = runif(10), bar2 = anno_barplot(runif(10)), annotation_name_rot = 90)
Heatmap(mat, name = "mat", top_annotation = column_ha, right_annotation = row_ha)


Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0
